# "Failed to fetch" for specific package versions leads to aborted `apt upgrade`

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I've just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04. I'm not sure if that went alright, because when I try to run `sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing` now, a subset of packages cannot be retrieved from the ubuntu archives, making the entire upgrade fail:

```
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-core_7.3.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.18-13ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/texlive-bin/texlive-binaries_2021.20210626.59705-1build1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dvisvgm/dvisvgm_2.13.1-1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/libmysqlclient21_8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_i386.deb Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/libmysqlclient21_8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

When I visit the archive website in my browser and click on those specific package versions that `apt` failed to fetch, the download fails as well, but *any other package version downloads fine*. I have tried using the main server and several other mirrors instead of my local (GB) server. This issue has now persisted for several days, meaning not only the upgrade for these packages fails, but all upgrades are blocked. How can I resolve this?

Comment: When you switched from your country mirror to the main archive; did you `sudo apt update` to update your software lists for the new source?

Comment: Yes, I did. Note that this also affects downloads of these specific package versions via the browser, from the main server and a few country mirrors I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using another network for upgrading just those six problematic packages. Once those packages were upgraded, I moved back onto my original network and was able to perform all other upgrades as normal. I never managed to find the exact cause of this issue, however.